# Check conditional statement inside a definition

Tags: c++, macros

I faced a problem for generating a function name in c++ using macros.
The thing is, I have a definition in part of my code similar to these lines:

```
#define FUNC_GENERATOR(stream_, port_no_)\
static void ISR##port_no_##ROUTINE(void);\
(stream_ == STREAM1) ? (void STREAM1##HANDLER(void) {ISR##port_no_##ROUTINE();} : ((void)(0))\
(stream_ == STREAM2) ? (void STREAM2##HANDLER(void) {ISR##port_no_##ROUTINE();} : ((void)(0))\
```

OK, I know it needs explanation, let me explain what I meant to do:
with FUNC_GENERATOR I want to generate an ISR routine based on the port_no_ (port number) and then decide which stream is selected so I could put this routine inside the corresponding stream ISR Handler.
So, the conditional statements in this definition checks if I wanted to generate a function for STREAM1 or STREAM2 and if it's for the correct STREAMx, then it puts the routine inside its Handler, if it's not correct, it does nothing. Somewhere else in my code, STREAM1 and STREAM2 are defined.

As, you have already guessed, it doesn't work. I used many many forms of macro but I couldn't overcome this problem.
The main question is how to do it properly, so that I can use this kind of definition with the given statement about my goal.

Comment: How do you intend using this macro? Show us a full example code, that we can see all context ([mcve]), this should be used in. Otherwise I am afraid, we cannot help you giving concise answers.

Comment: You're trying to put a function definition inside a conditional statement? That will never work. Probably templates are the way to go. Templates are much more flexible in almost every situation than macros.

Comment: A conditional expression (they are not statements) chooses between the values of two expressions, and a function definition is not an expression. You also can't put arbitrary expressions at file or namespace scope, and you can't define a function in the places where you *can* put arbitrary expressions.

Comment: As a first step, write some valid code without any macros. Then you can start thinking about how to reduce duplication, whether with macros or templates or by some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not possible to do this kind of operation using macros. There are many other ways to do this, like using templates, but there is a special reason why I'm using macros. It's more general compared to the things like templates. Moreover, I want to initialize and instantiate and define many other objects simultaneously.
I think I was seeking something huge and difficult, but the answer was as simple as adding bunch of other defines and creating another function like macro to use my ISR in its corresponding handler.

Thank you all.